# Parsing HTML to retrieve terms

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing

I have created a crawler. So, now I have a bunch of URLs which were crawled.
I need to create an index using a vector space or at least a List of all terms inside HTML.

Suppose this random webpage https://www.centralpark.com/things-to-do/central-park-zoo/polar-bears/

How do I parse all terms in that webpage? I kinda don't understand should I grab text between particular tags or maybe something else or which library I should use? I'm completely lost.

Here is what I need to do with that HTML:

> You can use a html parser online, but in principle, you can use the
>   text in the body of the html ... or between tags like
>   this p /p, h2 /h2.

Any help to parse above HTML is appreciated.

EDIT:
I'm trying BeautifulSoup:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import  urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

    my_url='https://www.centralpark.com/things-to-do/central-park-zoo/polar-bears/'
    # opening up connection
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    # close connection
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, features="html.parser")
    print(page_soup.p)
```

How to take all text elements in to List?

Ex:

```
<p>This is p<\p>
<p>This is another p<\p>
<h1>This is h1<\h1>
maybe some other text tags
```

to

```
List = ['This is p','This is another p','This is h1',...]
```

Comment: Presumably your research highlighted the `BeautifulSoup` library? What's wrong with that?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please include your current coding attempt and explain what isn't working. Also, may it absolutely clear what the expected result is e.g. what does _terms_ mean in relation to that page?

Comment: @QHarr , yes it is hw. I implemented crawler. I'm creating a search engine. Now I need to parse html, by terms I mean text (every word, literally word, between p tags maybe) within html. If I somehow put every single word into List, I'll able to continue process that text. I don't know from where to start, I don't understand what text is (which tags), and how to catch that text, that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: You will need to learn how to inspect HTML. p tags, for example, are paragraphs. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element). You can use F12/dev tools or right click inspect on items of interest to explore the relevant HTML. If content is not js/lazy loaded you may be able to simply use BeautifulSoup and parse the HTM, otherwise, you may need to use browser automation such as via selenium. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure

Comment: Post your code. Even if it is not yet working as you want it to. You will want to use bs4's `.find_all()` to locate `<strong>` spans within a `<p>` paragraph.

Comment: @J_H , I've started  working with BeautifulSoup. Updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, you're making progress!

I recommend that you `pip install requests` and use that. You'll find it is a much more convenient API than urllib. (Also, simply `soup` would be the usual name for that variable.)

> How to take all text elements in to List?

It's as easy as this:

```
    print(list(page_soup.find_all('p')))
```

which explains why so many people are quite fond of BeautifulSoup.

This displays an excerpt from the page:

```
    paragraphs = page_soup.find_all('p')
    for p in paragraphs:
        print(str(p)[:40])

<p class="lead">There are no longer any 
<p><strong>Polar Bear</strong> (Ursus Ma
<p><strong>Zoo collection includes:</str
<p><strong>Found in the wild:</strong> A
<p><strong>See Them at the Central Park 
<p><strong>Description:</strong> The mal
<p><strong>Zoo Bear Habitat:</strong> Th
<p><strong>What do they eat:</strong>  T
<p><strong>Life span:</strong> 25 to 30 
<p><strong>Threats:</strong> Global warm
<p><strong>Fun Facts:</strong> A newborn
<p>Copyright © 2004 - 2018 Greensward Gr
```

It is important to note that `p` is *not* a string.
It is an object that can be searched, just like the soup it came from.
You might want to find `<strong>` spans within it.

Comment: Thank you. It is much easier than I expected

Comment: 1 last question, can I say that I grabbed all text within a webpage if I process <p>, <h1>-<h6> tags? Maybe there are some other tags which I should consider?

Comment: There are lots of relevant tags, such as `<div>`. And they can be nested, one within another. So you might want to start with `<body>`, which has all the text, then look at the one or more body elements, and recursively look at each of *those* elements.

Answer (score 1):

I find the following syntax using a css [element/type selecto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors)r and a list comprehension easier to read

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.centralpark.com/things-to-do/central-park-zoo/polar-bears/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
paragraphs = [paragraph.text for paragraph in soup.select('p')]
print(paragraphs)
```